# Why does my site redirect back to the Login screen when I click an external provider button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm upgrading an ASP.Net MVC4 site to MVC5, and implementing the new OWIN Authentication methods in the process.

I've copied over the action methods from the Account controller on a blank MVC5 project.

The problem is, when I click an external provider button (e.g. Google) I just get redirected back to the login page again. The second time I click it, I do get taken to the Google account page, but then the browser gets redirected to the Account/External login page.

What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the `<authentication>` element in your web.config file. It is probably still saying

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

Changing it to `<authentication mode="None">` should fix the problem.

For good measure, remove the FormsAuthentication module from your webserver modules section:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
     <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

The problem is that the FormsAuthentication module looks out for any responses with a 401 (Unauthorised) code and changes them into a redirect request to your login page.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and Samuel Jack's answer did help me, but I had to make a slight change.

For me, adding the

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
```

under the "handlers" section did not work. Instead, I had to add it under the "modules" section as below and the issue was resolved.

Here is how my web.config looks.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
```

Note that in my case, there already was a

```
<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
```

in my web.config but that did not help solve the issue. I don't know how it got there so I left it alone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It should be removed from modules, not handlers, so I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem for 1 day straight, but sometimes I have some bad days and my attention to details is low.

But my problem was a bit awkward. My external logins were fine for like few months and suddenly stopped working and I didn't touched that code at all however my webconfig was...

```
 <location path="something/somethingelse">
     //other stuff that made it hard to see because is pretty long
   <system.webServer>
      <modules>
         <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
         <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      </modules>
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

Luckily I figured this out before posting a question I was about to write and made me see that location tag.

I have no idea **why** it **worked** in the first place then got broken later. I haven't updated any reference, did literally nothing to this for weeks.